# Discrete Mathematics - Understanding Graph Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm new to this topic in Discrete Mathematics and was just wondering what does it mean a question like finding the number of edges a graph has depending on the degree sequence. Also, how would I draw a graph?

How many edges does a graph have if its degree sequence is 4, 3, 3, 2, 2? Draw such a graph.

Comment: One possible way to draw such a graph by trial and error is to start by drawing a vertex with $4$ edges coming out of it but going nowhere, same for the other vertices, then see if you can connect everything up to form a "proper" graph.  This should also give you some insight into your first question.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is "does such a graph exist?". You use theorems like Havel-Hakimi or Erdos-Gallai to show that a simple graph exists or not (obviously, if you allow non-simple graphs, the necessary and sufficient condition occurs when the sum of all degrees is even). You can also use Havel-Hakimi's repeated application to construct one graph (not necessarily unique, even up to isomoprhism) by starting with one of the degree sequences that you're given in Havel-Hakimi, constructing a graph, then modifying it. You can find the details on Havel-Hakimi in any introductory graph theory text along with its proof (which will help you work backwards on it).

For such a small graph though on 5 vertices, you can just guess it out. Clearly, one node is connected to all of the others. Then drawing a picture is easy with a bit of guess work (assuming such a graph exists). In Mathematica, you can do ShowGraph[RealizeDegreeSequence[{4,3,3,2,2}]] to get

[image: Degree]

To get the number of edges in a graph from a degree sequence, use the handshaking lemma: 
$$\sum_{v \in V} d(v) = 2 |E|$$
(proof is left as an easy exercise to the reader).